# how to create hash from xml in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, hash

I am trying to create hash from xml file

```
Hash.from_xml <<-EOX
<user>
  <id>1</id>
  <user-name>ryan</user-name>
</user> 
EOX
```

when i use the above code it works fine and gives 
`{ :user => { :id => 1, :user_name => "ryan" } }`

my problem is I have the xml part as a string

```
@xml ="<user><id>1</id><user-name>ryan</user-name></user>"
```

And trying to do following but its not working

```
Hash.from_xml <<-EOX
  @xml 
EOX
```

Comment: For info if any one comes down to this post: from_xml uses rexml library which is very slow in processing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need the mutli-line string EOX stuff:

```
Hash.from_xml @xml
```

Comment: Note this method has problems with arrays of objects inside a root node

Answer (score 0):

```
Hash.from_xml(@xml)
#=> {"user"=>{"id"=>"1", "user_name"=>"ryan"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
Hash.from_xml @xml
```

The from_xml method is taking a string argument.  In your working example, you are passing in a multiline string.